# Reference about EDS penetration/emission depth

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, x-rays

EDS is an acronym for Energy Dispersive X-ray Spectroscopy. I know, that depth of sample from which it collects signal is something between 1 and 5 microns, however I cannot find any written source. Can you recommend any article where it explicitly says something about it?

Answer (score 1):

"Scanning Electron Microscopy and X-ray Microanalysis" by Goldstein, Newbury, Joy et al. Released by Springer.

Also, there's a [Nist](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Star/Text/method.html) database on stopping powers, which is probably more accurate than the first order approximations in Goldstein.